# Invalid setup on a non-overridable member:

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd, virtual

I'm trying to test the function GetcallEntityBycallEntity (Guid callId) with Mock library.

this function calls another class that does not implement any interface.

> protected virtual CallFacade CallFacade()
>          {
>              return new CallFacade();
>          }
>
> ```
>    public Note GetCallEntityByCallEntity(Guid CallEntity)
>    {
>         myCall= null;
>
>        **CallFacade**  callFacade = Get CallFacade();
>
>       if (CallEntity!= Guid.Empty)
>        {
>            myCall = callFacade.GetCallByEntityId(CallEntity);
>        }
>        return myCall;
>    }
> ```

CallFacade  Not is an Interface

in my test:

```
[TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialization()
    {
        IoCMocks.Initialize();
        CommonCallFacadeMock = new CommonCallFacadeMock();
    }
public void GetCallEntityByNoteEntity_GetCall_ReturnValidCall()
    {
        //Arrange
        CallmyNote = GetmyCall(); //private method. == Call.CreateCall();


        //Stubs
        CommonCallFacadeMock.MockCallFacade.Setup(x => x.GetCallByEntityId(ExistingCallEntity)).Returns(myCall);
        //Action
        var obtained = CommonCallFacadeMock.GetCallEntityByCallEntity(ExistingCallEntity);

        CommonCallFacadeMock.MockCallFacade.Verify(x => x.GetCallByEntityId(It.IsAny<Guid>()), Times.Once());


    }
```

Comment: when I make the Setup of mock ( Stubs) : I get the warning -->Invalid setup on a non-overridable member:

Answer (score 1):

You get this error message because MOQ can mock only interfaces, abstract methods or properties on abstract classes, virtual methods or properties on concrete classes.

You have to mark method `GetCallByEntityId` as virtual.

There is [an old discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moqdisc/LgLjZ9AX8nQ) in "Moq Discussions" google group about virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks for respond me. I try to mark as virtual but the question, I think, I need to have an Interface  ICallFacade  callFacade = Get CallFacade(); and this method as protected virtual CallFacade CallFacade() { return new CallFacade(); } ......I still get the error

Comment: 1. At which line of code do you have an error message? You have the only one setup "CommonCallFacadeMock.MockCallFacade.Setup(x => x.GetCallByEntityId(ExistingCallEntity)).Returns(myCall);" and method GetCallByEntityId should be virtual or belong to interface ICallFacade.


2. Yes, it is reasonable to have ICallFacade. You can provide it as constructor dependency (parameter of constructor) or method dependency (parameter of a method)